# Positioning elements with flexbox and :after

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On a site I'm working on I have a banner at the top of the page which is 300px tall, that contains the title of the page and an underline.

This is the markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="banner">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Terms and conditions</h1>
                <img class="center-block" src="assets/img/common/header-blue-underline.png" width="158" height="10" alt=""/> 
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="banner-nav">
        <ul class="get-in-touch-links">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Which makes this (with styling)

[image]

To acheive this I have used margins to force spacing, which isn't very easy to maintain when titles get longer.

I would rather use flexbox to align the text within the banner, so that the text will stay vertically central, regardless of the amount of content.

For instance, I could apply a class like this to #banner

```
.flex{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The issue is: the image does not naturally float under the text when using this method.

So I tried:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="banner" class="flex">

      <h1>Nulla quis lo</h1>



    </div>

    <div id="banner-nav">
        <ul class="get-in-touch-links">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>

#banner h1:after{
            content: url(assets/img/common/header-blue-underline.png);
        }
```

So that the underline is automatically placed under the h1 but it just sits next to the h1 element.

[image]

Essentially I'm trying to stop bodging things and use modern standards to position things accurately.

Comment: Can you create a runnable example that we can tweak?  My guess is that you need to add `flex-direction: column;` to `.flex {...}`, but I'd like to test a few different ideas.

Comment: Shall I make a codepen or something? Or literally create a runnable on this page?

Comment: whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use `flex` from the main container if it has a set `height` and use `margin` to dispatch its children *(gradient can also be used to underline partially the title)*

```css
.flex {
  color: rgb(253, 253, 254);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 250px;/* can be any heights and units */
  background: 
       linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7))/* gradient used here to darken the bg image , demo purpose */,
       url(http://lorempixel.com/800/200/technics/6) center / cover;
}

#banner {
  margin: auto;/* center in the container and push others to the the edges */
}

#banner h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(18, 153, 221, 0.9), rgba(18, 153, 221, 0.9)) no-repeat bottom center / 90px 5px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#banner-nav {
  background: rgba(18, 153, 221, 0.8);
}


/* quick bad reset*/

ul,
li,
a {
  color: inherit;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex">
  <div id="banner">
    <h1>Nulla quis lotest</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="banner-nav">
    <ul class="get-in-touch-links">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**codepen demo to play with**](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vWLgyX)

Answer (score 4):

As a pseudo element's default display is `inline`, your `::after` will line up side-by-side with the text.

You can either make it a block, give it a width and use auto margin to center it

```
#banner h1::after {
        content: url(assets/img/common/header-blue-underline.png);
        display: block;
        width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
```

or much simpler, make your `h1` a flex container, and it will push the `::after` to its own row

```
#banner h1{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }

#banner h1:after{
        content: url(assets/img/common/header-blue-underline.png);
    }
```

---

A possible upgrade would be to use the pseudo *as a line*, to avoid loading an image.

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  width: 40%;
  height: 6px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
  <h1> A header with a blue line </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to give both of these examples a whirl and will report back. I appreciate your detailed answer though

Comment: @JesseOrange I made a mistake, where I suggested a solution based on the `::after` were a sibling to `h1`, which is not :) ... updated my answer a proper solution